# How to implement Sraech bar in FLatList react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am trying to add search bar in FlatList  ,Here am fetching data from API and populating on FlatList ,but I have to filter that list ,because it may contain many data . So please help me for that . I have tried few examples but getting error so sometimes nothing is happening .Please take a look and help

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { View, Text, TextInput,   
    FooterTab,Button,TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, StyleSheet,
     ActivityIndicator ,Header,FlatList} from 'react-native';
     import {Icon} from 'native-base';
    import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';  
    import { SearchBar } from 'react-native-elements';   

  export default  class RenderList extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Selected Item',
    header: null,
  };
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      data: null,
      loading: true,
      search: '',
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createViewGroup();
  }

  createViewGroup = async () => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(
        'http://Dsenze/userapi/grouphier/viewgroup',
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({
            password: 'admin',
            username: 'admin',
            viewall: 'false',
            id: [4],
            startlimit: '0',
            valuelimit: '10',
          }),
        }
      );

      const responseJson = await response.json();

      const { groupData } = responseJson;

      this.setState({
        data: groupData,
        loading: false,
      });
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  clickedItemText(clickedItem) {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Item', { item: clickedItem });
  }
  updateSearch = search => {
    this.setState({ search });
  };
  keyExtractor = ({ id }) => id.toString();
  keyExtractor = ({ name }) => name.toString();

  renderItem = ({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.item}
      activeOpacity={0.4}
      onPress={() => {
        this.clickedItemText(item);
      }}>
      <Text>Hospital Id {item.id}</Text>
      <Text>Hospital Name {item.name}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
        }}
      />
    );
  };


  render_FlatList_header = () => {

    var header_View = (

    <View style={styles.header_footer_style}>

      <Text style={styles.textStyle}> FlatList Header </Text>

    </View>

    );

    return header_View ;

  };

  render() {
    const { loading, data } = this.state;


    return (
      <ScrollView>
        <View style={styles.container1}>

          {this.state.loading ? (
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" />

          ) :

          (
            <FlatList 
              data={data}
              renderItem={this.renderItem}
             keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
             ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
             ListHeaderComponent={this.render_FlatList_header}

            />
          )}
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks ...

Comment: Would be great if you add a working copy in https://snack.expo.io/

Comment: The code I have written , in that data is coming on flat list .. api and data all is working .

Comment: Sir..  you mean I'll put my code in snack.expo.io ?

Comment: Yes, that will be easy for debugging.

Comment: Ok sure  .  https://snack.expo.io/HJE0H_xLN

Comment: haha, I didnt mean just copy paste in there :P
Thats okay, here, https://snack.expo.io/BymD8deLV
So you want a search bar, on input it should search from the flatlist? Right now you have 11 data, if you type hospita name 'banaglore' in search it will show only one item in flatlist?

Comment: :) yes.. I am just learning .. since last 20 days , so not expert sorry .. There are 11 data so I want ki , I can filter any particular data if I write in search box , like name of hospital ..

Comment: please help.....

Comment: Hi Subhendu  ,please  help ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188961/discussion-between-subhendu-kundu-and-abhigyan-gaurav).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to keep an original values of your data, then you can filter it based on the key inputs and set the state to show in your flatlist.
For example, on change text on if input you filterout the matching substring of the object and put it in a new array and set it in `filterByValue` array which will be shown in the flatlist.

```
onSearchInputChange = (text) => {
    const filterByValue = this.state.data.filter(x => 
     x.name.toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()));
    this.setState({
      searchText: text,
      filterByValue
    });
  }
```

then pass the data of flatlist as

```
<FlatList 
   data={filterByValue}
   renderItem={this.renderItem}
   keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
   ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
   ListHeaderComponent={this.render_FlatList_header}
/>
```

For working example try this
https://snack.expo.io/rJY0gYlIV

Comment: Sorry but one more question , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54687419/not-able-to-download-qrcode-in-png-format .. I'll be thankful to you :)